# Getting "Could not authenticate you" at connection stage with Abraham's TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to let users log in to my site using a simple twitter log in. I've tried following the instructions on https://twitteroauth.com/redirect.php but that came up with an "Bad Authentication Error" until I removed the getenv() from the keys.

Here's my code:

```
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '<<MY KEY>>');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '<<MY SECRET>>');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://www.example.com/inside/index.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
```

And the response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}' in /home/sites/site2/web/inside/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:141 Stack trace: #0 /home/sites/site2/web/inside/index.php(12): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/request_t...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/sites/site2/web/inside/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 141
```

Every search I've done on SO and Google seems to related to an older version of twitteroauth - I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is coming up against this - the solution I found was to ditch TwitterOAuth and I used [HybridAuth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) instead. Far easier.